# Not able to continue loop after exception in Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to return list of number from a stored procedure. My stored procedure gets stopped in for loop when exception occur. I have added exception clause  and control is going inside the exception clause to continue the loop but still no luck.

How to continue the loop when exception occur? Thanks.

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getNumber(l_list IN CUSTOMLIST, l_output OUT NUMLIST) 
     IS
            n_num varchar2(5);
     BEGIN
            l_output := NUMLIST();

            FOR i IN l_list.FIRST .. l_list.LAST LOOP
                            l_output.EXTEND(l_list.LAST);
                      BEGIN      
                        SELECT NUM into n_num 
                            FROM sometable WHERE some condition;

                            l_output(i) := n_num;
                            EXCEPTION 
                            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TRUE');
                             CONTINUE;
                      END;
            END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: try checking your l_list , may be it has just 1 value .

Comment: It has 3 items . First and 3 rd are true and 2 nd is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I posted in question is working when I restart the SQL developer. Something was wrong at SQL developer level when I copy paste the EXCEPTION clause. But when I type the EXCEPTION clause it's started showing be no_data_found option and that one I selected and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should handle other exceptions too.
Try with adding

```
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
       [statements]
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that my control is going inside exception block but Continue statement is not moving to next loop.

Comment: It would be way more helpful if you could show us exactly what error information you see when the loop terminates. Your use of continue above is entirely unnecessary. It will by default continue if you do not re-raise the exception and simply display "true".

Comment: @StevenFeuerstein - I was getting no data found error. I am passing three list items in which second item is false aa per the where clause and I am expecting to continue loop to 3rd item and return 1 st and 3 rd item but I am getting only first item and exit from the loop.